# "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" when calling bootstrap functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble calling bootstrap-java functions from my rails application. 
Currently I am trying to get a simple example with some tooltips to work.

The strange thing though is that the bootstrap menus etc. are working fine, so the bootstrap gem must be integrated OK?

Here is the code for my view:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tooltip-examples a").tooltip({
        placement : 'top'
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="bs-example"> 
    <ul class="tooltip-examples list-inline">
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Default tooltip">Tooltip</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

And my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

But when I load the page the browser console (Chrome) returns:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

on this line:

```
$(".tooltip-examples a").tooltip({
```

Seems like it cant find the tooltip() function?

**EDIT:**
I just noticed that it returns the same error when I try to call the fancybox gems javascript functions. Could this be related? and maybe be a general problem with my rails setup?

**EDIT 2**

Here are the the full generated HTML code (I have deleted the .css includes and navigation):

```
<html>
<head>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/core.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/widget.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/accordion.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/position.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/menu.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/autocomplete.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/button.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/datepicker.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/mouse.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/draggable.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/resizable.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/dialog.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/droppable.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-blind.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-bounce.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-clip.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-drop.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-explode.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-fade.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-fold.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-highlight.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-size.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-scale.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-puff.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-pulsate.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-shake.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-slide.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/effect-transfer.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/progressbar.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/selectable.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/selectmenu.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/slider.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/sortable.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/spinner.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/tabs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/tooltip.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/affix.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/alert.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/button.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/carousel.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/collapse.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/tab.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/transition.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/modal.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/tooltip.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/popover.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/about.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/project_posts.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/projects.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/static_pages.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/welcome.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="ANhRc1muZwg+kQ6D2byl4OJPeRjwHEEEjgv4v+reTgA=" name="csrf-token" />

</head>
<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        NAVIGATION...
</nav>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tooltip-examples a").tooltip({
        placement : 'top'
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="bs-example"> 
    <ul class="tooltip-examples list-inline">
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Default tooltip">Tooltip</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you load jQuery and friends before you use them?

Comment: Try using `jQuery()` instead of `$()` if you have other JS libraries included.

Comment: tooltip is a [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) function. make sure you have included that.

Comment: @aniskhan001 then I just get the same error at the line: "jQuery((document).ready(function(){" instead.

Comment: @dfsq No, not sure! How can I check it?

Comment: @karthikr I have now added the [link](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails) gem, but it didn't resolve anything.

Comment: In your case jQuery should be included in `head` section before `$(document).ready(function(){...`.

Comment: Then surely you didn't loaded jQuery on your document.

Comment: can you see a reference to jquery-ui in the generated html ?

Comment: @dfsq I have made an edit with the generated code, it seems fine I think?

Comment: @aniskhan001 I made a typo before, now it doesn't complain about jQuery, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try also adding

> //= require jquery-ui

EDIT

Try moving the bootstrap import above the jquery import

Also might be worth changing to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass for importing bootstrap. Not sure if its better, but its the one I generally use without issue

FURTHER EDIT

For those working with Rails, this is already defined in bootstrap.js.coffee with `$(".tooltip").tooltip()`. Just make sure to include `//= require bootstrap` in your application.js

So maybe try removing your

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tooltip-examples a").tooltip({
        placement : 'top'
    });
});
```

and see if it works

Comment: I added the gem, but it didn't resolve the problem :(

Comment: I am using bootstrap-sass already: "gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'"
Moving bootstrap import above jquery in application.js just crashes all java related stuff. Removing the javascript in the file does nothing either.

Comment: What error is thrown when you remove the tooltip code ?

Comment: Not sure if this will help but maybe try swapping your tooltip with this and see if it works (taken straight from bootstrap)

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>`

Comment: Nope, nothing happens. No errors, no tooltip, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

put Jquery js file on top of the boostraps links